# JPEG Compression causes GDI+ Exception

Tags: vb.net, compression, jpeg, gdi+

So, I'm currently working on a LAN-Video-Streaming program, which records single images and sends them over. Because it would be too much to send 30 1920x1080 pictures per second, to get 30FPS, I did some research and found JPEG-Compression. The problem is, that when I try to save the compressed JPEG, it throws an `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException`, with the additional information: `General error in GDI+.`

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Stream() Handles StreamTimer.Tick

    If Streaming = True Then

        Try
            ScreenCap = New Bitmap(Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height)

            GFX = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenCap)
            GFX.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, ScreenCap.Size)

            Dim Frame As New Bitmap(ScreenCap, Resolution.Split(";")(0), Resolution.Split(";")(1))

            Dim jpgEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Dim myEncoder As Encoder = Encoder.Quality
            Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
            Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, Compression)
            myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

            Frame.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\LSSFrame.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters) 'Error occurs in this line

            Using FS As New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\LSSFrame.jpg", FileMode.Open)
                Frame = Image.FromStream(FS)
                FrameSizeStatus.Text = Math.Round(FS.Length / 1000) & "KB"
                FS.Close()
            End Using

            PreviewBox.Image = Frame
            FPSStat += 1

            FlushMemory()

            If ViewerIPs.Count > 0 Then

                For i = 0 To ViewerIPs.Count - 1
                    SendFrame(ViewerIPs(i), Frame)
                Next

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            LostFrames += 1
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You arent disposing of things properly which can lead to that error.  Consult the posts to the right under **Related**.  I doubt you will ever get 30 snaps per second though.

Comment: Well, how do I do that then? I know how to dispose things, but **what** should I dispose? By the way, I tested id, and it even works up to 60FPS. :D

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look through it again and correct my mistakes. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part, you are not disposing of the `Graphics` or `Bitmap` objects you create.  The error message is not very helpful, but not disposing of those will leave resources unrecovered.

There is also a lot going on in that procedure.  If it were broken into parts it might be easier to fine-tune for performance and such.

```
' form level objects
Private jEncParams As EncoderParameters
Private jpgEncoder As ImageCodecInfo
...
' inititalize somewhere when the process starts:
Dim quality As Int64 = 95

jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim myjEnc As Imaging.Encoder = Imaging.Encoder.Quality

jEncParams = New EncoderParameters(1)
' quality is inverse to compression
jEncParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(myjEnc, quality)
```

Since the encoder and quality elements are not going to change for each screen snap, create them once and resuse them.  Then your timer event:

```
Dim scrBytes = GetScreenSnap(1280, 720)
' do something to send them....maybe queue them?
Console.WriteLine("image size: {0}k", (scrBytes.Length / 1024).ToString)
```

Optimizing `SendFrame` is outside the scope of this Q/A, but getting the screen shot is separate from sending.

```
Private Function GetScreenSnap(w As Int32, h As Int32) As Byte()

    Using bmpScrn As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScrn)
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmpScrn.Size)
        End Using       ' done with graphics

        Using bmpThumb As New Bitmap(bmpScrn, w, h),
            ms As New MemoryStream
            bmpThumb.Save(ms, jpgEncoder, jEncParams)
            Return ms.ToArray
        End Using        ' dispose of bmp
    End Using            ' dispose of bmpScrn

End Function
```

For no particular reason, I am thumbnailing the entire screen.  Yours seems off using `Bounds.Width, Bounds.Height` since that would refer to the form.  It would only work as a screen snapshot if the form is maximized.  keypoints:

- This is predicated on the idea that you can/will be sending the byte array in a stream.  As such, I leave it as a byte array rather than creating a BMP only to (presumably) convert it back later.
- There is no need to create a disk file to get the size.  If the array contains encoded bytes, it will be the same size.
- I've never used the COMPRESSION param, but I know Quality is inverse to compression.

Resulting sizes for various Quality factors:

> 100 = 462
>       95 = 254
>       90 = 195
>       80 = 147

Strictly speaking you do not need the encoder, `bmpThumb.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)` will also work but a single encoder object offers more fine tuning.

---

For the sending part, you might want a `Stack`, `Queue` or `LinkedList` to store the byte array.  This would further isolate getting images from sending them.  The collection would be a sort of ToDo/ToSend list.

Then, if there are multiple recipients, I'd look into perhaps doing `SendFrame` as a `Task`, perhaps sending 2-3 at a time.  There might be a point where the number of recievers interferes with how fast you can grab new ones.