# Screen capturing is not working when windows form is invisible

Tags: .net, vb.net

The following program does not capture the screen when I am running the form invisible. timer is started in form load event.

Is there any way to make this program to capture screen in form invisible mode. Please help me to sort out this problem. Thanks

```
Private keepInvisible As Boolean

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()
    keepInvisible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    keepInvisible = False


    Dim ScreenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Using g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), ScreenSize)
    End Using

    screenGrab = New Bitmap(screenGrab, 800, 600) 'Defines the new image size

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt") 'I want the date to be the name of the image

    screenGrab.Save(Application.StartupPath & "/" & Filename & ".Jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    If keepInvisible Then
        MyBase.SetVisibleCore(False)
    Else
        MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working?  Why are you using `SetVisibleCore` rather than just Me.Visible?  What is the interval of the timer.  If it is too small, you could be writing to the same file over.  You also are not disposing of resources.  If it runs a while, you will get a GDI exception

Comment: I tried me.hide it does not make the form invisible. I tried without SetVisibleCore initially it worked fine but after that only I added SetVisibleCore now form is invisible but screen capturing is not working

Comment: You have other issues somewhere because `Me.Visible` and `Me.Hide` should always make the form invisible

Comment: I had code handy from [this recent similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34575453/1070452) and used it on a timer with Me.Visible and it saves files fine...I did tweak the name so it was more than 1 sec different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> timer is started in form load event

That's the cue, the Load event does not fire.  Because you overrode SetVisibleCore() and decided to keep the window invisible.  That *also* prevents the Load event from firing.  It won't fire until you actually make the window visible.  Very easy to diagnose with the debugger, just set a breakpoint on your event handler.

Just don't use the Load event, you don't need it at all.  Load is *only* necessary when you need to know the actual Location and Size properties of your form.  Everything else needs to go in the constructor of your class.  `Sub New` in a VB.NET app.  Unfortunately Load is the default event, a quirk inherited from VB6, so programmers tend to put too much stuff into it.  Just don't.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(value As Boolean)
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        value = False
        CreateHandle()
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
End Sub
```

Note the change in SetVisibleCore(), it still creates the native window, that ensures that the Close() method does what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks so much Hans, I called the timer.start from sub new() and it worked.